# Select (and remove) between tags without tags with Regular Expressions

Tags: html, regex, tags

i have the following example:

```
[ame="http://www.google.com"]Google - a search engine[/ame]
```

i have tried **[ame=.*](.*?)[/ame]** and it selects the tags and the text.

i need to select everything between the [ame][/ame] tags in order to delete it. I use Sublime Text that uses Regular Expressions but i cannot select only the text between tags and not the text with tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
(\[ame=[^\]]*\])(.*?)(\[\/ame\])
```

And replace with `$1$3`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vA6mZ3/6)

Comment: It is probably useful to make the first `*` non-greedy as well.

Comment: @acdcjunior you are right.. updated with negative character class.. which will give better performance than making it non greedy :)

Comment: Yes, it is correct if i choose $2 i get the text between tags but my problem is that i cannot use $ signs in Sublime Text, i need a regex just to select the text between tags and i can press the delete button and go on to the next result